# Create ASP.NET Core 6 Identity tables inside a existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I am using Entity Framework for my ASP.NET Core 6 application and now I want to add the Identity framework to my project. I want to make sure that the identity tables are added to my previously created database where the rest of my data is stored.

I've been searching quite a bit, but can't exactly find an appropriate solution for this.

I had found SQL queries for creating these tables, but these don't work for me either.

This is my code that I have in the program.cs:

```
// identity DB
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContextConnection") ??
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string not found")));
// AppDbContextDB
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContextConnection") ??
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string not found")));
```

Through the above way, the tables are not created. If I put them in a different connection string, they are created as normal.

Does anyone have a solution how I can automate this so that even when running my project, the identity framework tables are added to my previously created database.

Note: I am using Rider.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will be my solution :

```
public class UserDbContext 
{
...
}


public class AppDbContext : UserDbContext
{
...
}
```

And then in `program.cs` just register your `AppDbContext`